# How do I completely remove Symantec Endpoint Protection?

Tags: macos

I've tried to uninstall through the app but it asks for a password from the "Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager administrator". I'm an admin for this account on the Mac so I should be able to remove everything manually. How do I do that? I'm specifically using version 14.0.1.

Comment: [Uninstall Symantec Endpoint Protection for Mac](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH132120.html)

Comment: Tyson, weird. You just posted that link but when I go there, I get "Sorry, we can't seem to find that page." Are you logged in using your support account? I had this problem with a bunch of pages I found using Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there's a tool that will completely uninstall Symantec software from your Mac. [This page](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/kb20080427024142EN_EndUserProfile_en_us) describes how it works. Here's the direct download link to [RemoveSymantecMacFiles.zip](https://support.symantec.com/content/dam/mac/tools/RemoveSymantecMacFiles.zip).

In case the first link goes away, the easiest way to run it is to control-click on the download, choose "Open with..." -> "Terminal" and follow the instructions. You'll need to have admin privileges on the Mac but you won't need the "Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager administrator" password.

Comment: Confirmed. This works.